# When I move a view's frame it doesn't move: why?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pin a bar (amongst other things) to the bottom of the screen. The code is:

```
    var screen = UIScreen.mainScreen()
    var bottom_view = view.viewWithTag(bottom_panel_tag)!
    var pad = bottom_view.frame.minX // is 0
    var screen_h = screen.bounds.maxY
    var screen_w = screen.bounds.maxX

    var b = CGRectMake( pad, screen_h - ( pad + bottom_view.frame.height ), screen_w - 2*pad, bottom_view.frame.height )
    bottom_view.frame = b
    bottom_view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

This called in viewDidLoad and I have stepped it in the debugger so I know it runs. The view doesn't move (or any other I change). There are no constraints. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you created bottom view using Storyboard ?

Comment: yes I did (type View)

Comment: ok try the code that I mentioned in my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.view.removeConstraints(self.view.constraints())
bottom_view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

add this line in `viewDidLoad()` before you change its frame.

> Explanation: Even if you don't add any Autolayout constraint it will
>   add at runtime if you create views using Storyboard & if you don't
>   want to use this solution then you should create view programatically
>   then it will change frame using your code only.

Comment: see this auto layout guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html

Comment: I don't think that's right either. Once Autolayout adds auto-resizing mask constraints, the constraints will take over and position the view. When you reposition your views and then something else changes the layout they'll jump back to their original positions.  Better to add outlets to their constraints and manipulate the outlets (or turn off Autolayout entirely if you want to use Autoresizing masks for the entire view controller)